# How to exclude files and directories in Git?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm working with Git version 2.11.0 and I don't know how exactly ignore some files and directories from my project.

In my project I've got a /vendor directory and inside of if files and other directories:

```
/vendor
/vendor/autolofile.php
/bin
/composer
/container-interop
/Demo
/psr
/zendframework
/zfcampus
```

Right now, I've got ignored all the /vendor directory and her files and subdirectories. But I want to exclude the file "autoload.php" and all the files that are inside of this directories structure:

```
/vendor/Demo/library/BBDD
/vendor/Demo/library/Data
/vendor/Demo/library/File
```

Now, I'm trying to see in status only all the files that are inside /vendor/Demo/library/BBDD but I'm not getting what I want. I've got this exit from `git status` command:

[image]

And what I have in my .ignore file is:

```
.vagrant/
vendor/*
!vendor/Demo
!vendor/Demo/library
!vendor/Demo/library/BBDD
!vendor/Demo/library/BBDD/*
config/development.config.php
data/cache/*
!data/cache/.gitkeep
phpunit.xml
ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log
```

What am I doing wrong? I would like to see in status all the files that are inside /vendor/Demo/library/BBDD, /vendor/Demo/library/Data and /vendor/Demo/library/File and the file in /vendor/autoload.php

Comment: You first have to run `git add vendor` and it will start to track `vendor/Demo`, `vendor/Demo/library` and the other non-ignored files.

Comment: It works!!!Thank you so much Samir Aguiar!!!

Comment: No worries, can I post it as an answer for you to accept then?

Comment: It seems that you original question is answered. But just in case you are wondering how `gitignore` really works (I always did), read my blog post about this topic: https://labs.consol.de/development/git/2017/02/22/gitignore.html I wrote this post also for myself as a reference, since I keep forgetting the `gitignore` specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have excluded those files from the `.gitignore` pattern, you still need to tell Git to track them by running `git add vendor`. It will then start showing you the differences in those files.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add `!vendor/autoload.php` file. Also i would suggest that your create another `.gitignore` file this time in the vendor folder, and put in the following:

```
*.*
!autoload.php
!Demo
```